# Silent print with multiple devices (chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, printing

So I have this POS (running Windows Embedded POSReady 7 as OS) and I have this web app (I'm using PL/SQL, javascript) that will print documents and recipts. There will be two printers connected to the POS, one is a laser printer (for the documents) and the other is a thermic printer (for the recipts).

I want to use Google Chrome's --kiosk --kiosk-printing BUT I need to switch printers because of the situation I described before, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Chrome App to achieve this.  You can connect to the USB and write PCL or image files directly to printer.

Our demo: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/apps/samples/usb-label-printer show how this can be achieved.

You do need to know the exact printer type you are connecting too and also write the device driver for it, but generally it is not to complex.